# Encryption & decryption in node aes-256-cbc goes Error

Tags: node.js, openssl, aes, cbc-mode, node-crypto

i need to encrypt my data with given key using aes-256-cbc algorithm but i am getting error "RangeError: Invalid key length" in node while using crypto library.

Php code results "w8mBJyHzQ3yJlkSvAX8t3qy9GVaUvBiOBAPFDXOzFMQ=" with

```
key = "9v6ZyFBzNYoP2Un8H5cZq5FeBwxL6itqNZsm7lisGBQ="
text = "Hello, Help me with this"
output is "w8mBJyHzQ3yJlkSvAX8t3qy9GVaUvBiOBAPFDXOzFMQ="
```

```
// Encryption Function
function encrypt($text, $key, $size = 16)
{
    $pad = $size - (strlen($text) % $size);
    $padtext = $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    $crypt = openssl_encrypt($padtext, "AES-256-CBC", base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, '0123456789abcdef');
    return base64_encode($crypt);
}
// Decryption Function
function decrypt($crypt, $key)
{
    $padtext = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($crypt), "AES-256-CBC", base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, '0123456789abcdef');
    $pad = ord($padtext[strlen($padtext) - 1]);
    if ($pad > strlen($padtext)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (strspn($padtext, $padtext[strlen($padtext) - 1], strlen($padtext) - $pad) != $pad) {
        $text = "Error";
    }
    $text = substr($padtext, 0, -1 * $pad);
    return $text;
}
```

And node code results "RangeError: Invalid key length"

```
key = "9v6ZyFBzNYoP2Un8H5cZq5FeBwxL6itqNZsm7lisGBQ="
data = "Hello, Help me with this"
output is "RangeError: Invalid key length"
```

```
function encrypt(data, key) {
    try {
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", atob(key), '0123456789abcdef');
        return cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
        // let encryption = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from(data, "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
        // return encryption.toString("base64");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error
    }

}
function decrypt(enc_data, key) {
    try {
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", atob(key), '0123456789abcdef');
        return (decipher.update(enc_data, 'base64', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf-8'));
        // const decryption = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(enc_data, "base64")), decipher.final()]);
        // return decryption.toString("utf8");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error
    }
}
```

Comment: A key passed as string in `createCipheriv()` (e.g. `atob(key)`) becomes UTF-8 encoded by default, which corrupts the data. Therefore replace `atob(key)` with `Buffer.from(atob(key), 'latin1')` or more efficiently with `Buffer.from(key, 'base64')`. The same holds for decryption, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", Buffer.from(keyStr,'base64'), Buffer.from(ivStr));`

Comment: Add details to your answer, and not just post a chunk of code. Explain why and how this helps to solve the problem OP has!

Comment: @Marc Sorry, maybe I thought this code solved the problem clearly. If you want to see more details, I just wrote an article in Chinese [php aes-256-cbc 转 node 加密实现](https://juejin.cn/post/7182233169163190329)